# Docker PHP Laravel Composer Memory exhausted Error

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have a Laravel project working on docker. When I want to add a package with "composer require" this error occurs:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83886080 bytes) in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90
```

I have changed the memory_limit in php.ini to "-1". The same error continues.

I have tried this command. Updates the composer.json file but then gets killed everytime.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer require waavi/sanitizer ~1.0
```

I have tried "composer update" same error about memory limit.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/GenericRule.php on line 36
```

composer.json file;

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "graham-campbell/flysystem": "^3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "1.0.29",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.16",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.18",
        "waavi/sanitizer": "~1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "jason-guru/laravel-make-repository": "^0.0.3",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/Helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using MacOS and Docker.

I've tried to composer clear-cache and composer install command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docker-compose.yml

```
php:
    container_name: php-server
    build: ./php/
    volumes:
      - ./..:/var/www
      - ./php/ini:/usr/local/etc/php // note that this line maps docker's /usr/local/etc/php
```

At your php Dockerfile directory under ini/conf.d/ create a file named memory_limit.ini So your directory will be .../php/ini/conf.d/memory_limit.ini Inside memory_limit.ini

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like the solution of Morteza Pouretemadi. But with some edits, because the original does not work for me.

My php image parsed additional .ini files. Something like this:

> Additional .ini files parsed:
> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mcrypt.ini,
> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini,
> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-redis.ini,
> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini,
> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini,

So, I've just created memory_limit.ini file in my project directory with settings for the  memory_limit param. And link the file (not a folder!) in the docker-compose.

```
php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build:
        context: .
    volumes:
      - ./public:/var/www/html/
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./php/ini/memory_limit.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory_limit.ini
```

Maybe it will help someone.